# How to read aloud Python List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

My question is about Python **List Comprehension** readability. When I come across code with complex/nested list comprehensions, I find that I have to re-read them several times in order to understand the intent.

Is there an intuitive way to read aloud list comprehensions? Seems like I should start "reading" from the middle, then read the ***if*** conditions (if any), and read the ***expression*** last.

Here's how I would read the follow line of code aloud, in order to understand it:

```
[(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]
```

"For each element in List x, and each element in List y, *if the two elements are not the same*, **create a list** of tuples."

Two examples that I am struggling with:
How would you read the following List Comprehensions aloud?

1. From another question in Stack Overflow: `[x for b in a for x in b]`
2. Python docs has this example:
   `[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]`

Any suggestions or pointers for ways to read aloud list comprehensions such that the intention becomes clearer is much appreciated.

Comment: don't read programming code aloud, that usually confuses more than it clarifies

Comment: @LieRyan My question is really around readability and understanding others' code. I wrote "read aloud" because I didn't know how else to phrase it.

Comment: readability doesn't imply reading aloud; I usually try to categorize the comprehension's loop form. There are three general ways to nest comprehensions, the `[... for ... in A for ... in B]` pattern forms a **cartesian product**; the `[... for ... in [... for ... in A]]` forms a **pipeline** (as in shell pipes); and the `[[... for ... in A] for ... in B]` creates a **multidimensional array**. After categorizing the looping's general form, interpreting the expression and if-condition part becomes trivial.

Comment: Since [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension?oldformat=true) follows the mathematical set-builder notation, in the more simple cases it may be helpful to grasp it using this notation itself: `S = {(x, y) : x ∈ {1,2,3} and y ∈ {3,1,4}, x != y}`. In more complex examples it's not very helpful, though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I usually unfold it in my mind into a generating loop, so for example

```
[(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y]
```

is the list comprehension for the generator

```
for x in [1,2,3]:
    for y in [3,1,4]:
        if x != y:
            yield (x, y)
```

---

### Example #1

`[x for b in a for x in b]` is the comprehension for

```
for b in a:
    for x in b:
        yield x
```

Example result for `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

---

### Example #2

`[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]` (note the inner expression is another comprehension!):

```
for i in range(4):
    yield [row[i] for row in matrix]
```

which is unfolded

```
for i in range(4):
    l = []

    for row in matrix:
        l.append(row[i])

    yield l
```

Comment: Thanks @AndiDog. Could you help me unfold the other two? Those are the ones that are tripping me up.

Comment: @Ram: There you go, hope that makes sense for you.

Comment: Yeah--this way of thinking about multi-part comprehensions should be the way list comprehensions are explained _everywhere_. The PEP does it, but most programmers don't read the PEP. I was mind-blown the day that I learned that the `[x for b in a for x in b]` nests in the direction it does and not in the other direction! But if I had started with the understanding that @AndiDog lays out above, I wouldn't have had that problem.

Comment: For beginners, I think it's quite misleading to present these list comprehensions as if they are implemented with an inner generator. The correct implementation can be seen in python docs, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 4):

"Construct a list of X's based on Y's and Z's for which Q is true."