# I'm having trouble figuring out this condensed code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def duplicate_count(s):
    return len([c for c in set(s.lower()) if s.lower().count(c)>1])
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how this code works. I was doing a codewars challenge to return the number of elements with duplicates in a string.

eg. Asasd --> 2

I came up with my own implmentation but I wasn't able to really understand what this code does. If anyone could point me in the direction, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Read about list comprehension in the docs

Comment: You don't understand your own code?

Answer (score 5):

This is, first of all, a highly inefficient solution to the problem. But let's break it down:

- [`s.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) would convert all the characters in a string to lower case:

  ```
  In [1]: s = "Hello, WORLD"

  In [2]: s.lower()
  Out[2]: 'hello, world'
  ```
- `set(s.lower())` would create a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (make sure to read about what sets are) of characters from a string - eliminating all the duplicates:

  ```
  In [3]: set(s.lower())
  Out[3]: {' ', ',', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w'}
  ```
- `for c in set(s.lower())` iterates over every single character in a set we created above
- for every character in this set, we apply this if condition: `if s.lower().count(c)>1`. The `count(c)` here would count how many times `c` appears in the string. The `>1` helps us to leave characters that are met more than 1 time in a string
- `[c for c in set(s.lower()) if s.lower().count(c)>1]` is *called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*. It is basically a short way of creating a list. Here, we are creating a list of characters that occur in a string more than one time. Check out *[this topic about how to verbalize and read the list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9061760/771848)*.
- `len()` then just gets us the length of the list

To summarize, you iterate over the unique characters in a given string and count which of them occur in a string more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

```
set(s.lower()) # gives unique elements in lower case
```

and

```
s.lower().count(c)>1 #checks if an element shows up more than once
```

All in all the function finds number of not unique elements in a string ,ignoring case.

I believe using `collections.Counter` is more efficient:

```
In [7]: from collections import Counter

In [8]: sum(v > 1 for v in Counter("Aabcc".lower()).values())

Out[8]: 2
```

Comment: Might be worth replacing `(x.lower() for x in "Aabcc")` with `"Aabcc".lower()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicate_count(s):

    result = []

    for c in set(s.lower()):
        if s.lower().count(c) > 1:
            result.append(c)

    return len(result)
```