# Where to put the if-condition inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I was given the function:

```
x**2 - 4*x + 6
```

and the task was to find the minimum integer values x between 0 and 10.
I had to use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(11):
    if 2*i-4==0:
        print("Minimum of the given function is:", i)
```

which gives me the correct answer `2`.

Now I should translate that as a list comprehension, but I do not know where to put the `if` statement:

```
mylist = [2*i-4==0 for i in range(11)]
print(mylist)
```

Of course, as an output I get a `true`/`false` list, with the index 2 being the correct `true`. But How do I include the if in my list comprehension?

Comment: There is absolutely no use in converting this to a list comprehension. You are not building a list here.

Comment: You'd have to put the `if` **after** the `for` loop, and only `i` before. But why build a list for one value?

Comment: `mylist = [i for i in range(11) if 2*i-4==0]` - but you only get one result so making this a list comp is not really helpfull....

Comment: try `next((i for i in range(11) if 2*i-4==0),-1)` you'll get -1 if no min, else you'll get the index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read aloud Python List Comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061760/how-to-read-aloud-python-list-comprehensions) - it explains how to unfold list comps whats what you need to do here in reverse ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finding a *single value*, not a list of values. A list comprehension makes little sense here.

Your error is in putting your test in the *value expression* section of the list comprehension. That's not a filter, that's the part where you build the new list values from the (filtered) elements from the loop.

Put an `if` *after* the `for` loop part:

```
[i for i in range(11) if 2 * i - 4 == 0]
```

This builds a list with just one element, the `i` value for which the value is true:

```
>>> [i for i in range(11) if 2 * i - 4 == 0]
[2]
```

If you must do this in a single line, use a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), then use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the first result from that:

```
gen = (i for i in range(11) if 2 * i - 4 == 0)
result = next(gen)
```

This will get you the minimal value for `i` even if there were to be multiple possible values for `i` where the `if` test would be true.

A generator is lazily evaluated; the loop stops the moment `i` reaches a value where the `if` test is true, and that one value is produced. `next()` only returns that first value, so no more iteration takes place. It's as if you used `break` in a `for` loop (except you can continue the loop later).

Note that this can raise a `StopIteration` exception if the generator doesn't produce *any* values. You can tell `next()` to return a default value in that case; a second argument to `next()` is returned if `StopIteration` would be raised otherwise:

```
result = next(gen, None)
```

You can combine the generator expression in the `next()` call; if a generator expression is the only argument you can omit the `(...)` parenthesis of the generator expression, otherwise include them so that it can be distinguished from other arguments:

```
result = next((i for i in range(11) if 2 * i - 4 == 0), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you *really* want to use a comprehension and not a classic loop here, since there is only one result, you could pass a generator to `next` with a default value just in case it doesn't find anything:

```
next((i for i in range(11) if 2*i-4==0),None)
```