# Particular List Comprehension

Tags: python

Could any one explain how to understand this particular list comprehension.

I have tried to decode the below list comprehension using [How to read aloud Python List Comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061760/how-to-read-aloud-python-list-comprehensions), but still not able to understand.

```
words  = "".join([",",c][int(c.isalnum())] for c in sen).split(",")
```

lets say:

```
sen='i love dogs'
```

So the output would be,

```
['i', 'love', 'dogs']
```

Comment: Thank you for this question. I had fun with this. But I'm very much hoping this is an exercise in a tutorial, or a first effort in obfuscation for someone. It's a great puzzle for folks getting started, but there are much simpler ways to accomplish this in practice, noted in the comments.

Comment: Also, I hope you get upvoted a fair amount. As I said, this is a great example of a question that will educate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way with  `split`:

```
print(sen.split())
```

Output:

```
['i', 'love', 'dogs']
```

**Explaining (your code):**

1. Iterates the string, and if the letter is nothing, like i.e space etc... , make it a comma.
2. After all of that use `split` to split the commas out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you've got this:

For each `character` (`c`) in the `sentence` (`sen`), create a list `[',', character]`.

If `character` is a letter or number (`.isalnum()`), add the character to the list being built by the comprehension. Or rather:

```
`[',', character][1]`.
```

If not, take the comma (","), and add that to the list being built by the comprehension.
Or rather:

```
`[',', character][0]`
```

Now, join the list together into a string:

```
`"".join(['I', ',', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ',', 'd', 'o', 'g', 's', ','])`
```

becomes

```
`"I,love,dogs,"`
```

Now and split that string using commas as the break into a list:

```
"I,love,dogs,".split(",")
```

becomes

```
`['I', 'love', 'dogs', '']`
```

The trick in here is that `[",",c][int(c.isalnum())]` is actually a slice, using the truth value of `isalnum()`, converted to an int, as either the zero index or the one index for the slice.

So, basically, if `c`,  is the character "b", for example, you have [',', character][1].

Hope this helps.

PS In my example, I'm using 'sen = 'i love dogs.' Can you spot the difference between your result and mine, and understand why it happens?

Here's code:

```
sen = 'I love dogs.'
words  = "".join([",",character][int(character.isalnum())] for character in sentence).split(",")
print(words)
```

Result:

```
['I', 'love', 'dogs', '']
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot. I was able to understand. Thanks for a thorough explaination. :)

Comment: @AyushGupta Happy to help! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted if it answered your question well? It would be appreciated, and is sort of the accepted practice around here. :) (Of course, only if the answer met your request/needs.) Cheers!