# How does this work -- sequence of split, int, nparray, and list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have a line of python code I'm trying to de-cipher from a function that parses a line from a file that's being read. I've annotated the lines that I do understand with comments

```
#split a line that is read from the file by spaces.
line = annotation_line.split()

#Open the file, represented by the first arg in the lines
#Lines are structured as below:
#/path/to/Image.png x1,y1,x2,y2,classNo x1,y1,x2,y2,classNo [etc]
#|Image file path  | Box for object 1  | Box for object 2  | Box for object n.
image = Image.open(line[0])

# grab the width and height of the image
iw, ih = image.size

#in this case 604 by 604.
h, w = input_shape

#line in question.
box = np.array([np.array(list(map(int,box.split(',')))) for box in line[1:]])
```

Here's what I think that the line does:
So first I break this up into individual functions.

The first parameter I break it up into this parameter:

```
stage1 = map(int,box.split(','))
```

Now *int* isn't a local or global variable,  but it is used as a function, and I cannot find what the function does, I assume that it turns something into an integer, and so I assume that this line maps  box into a sequence of integers. However, box isn't a global or local variable either, only defined in the line itself, so  It seems to be mapping nothing to nothing?

The next stage is as follows.

```
stage2 = [np.array(list(stage1) for box in line[1:]]
```

You've lost me here, turn into an array, the numpy (np is numpy) array of a list of everything of stage 1 for all boxes  in the parameters from the 2nd item in the line array to the end?  I'm not even sure that's a grammatically correct sentence.

What does this line of code in question exactly do? You can find  the full code on [this github page](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo3/utils.py).

Comment: First, this is an excellent question that asks what a line of code does... Is it the [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works) that is confusing? think of it as a for loop where box is what you're currently iterating on. You're right about int, its a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Comment: @Sayse the list function is confusing, as well as what data types are being passed into the functions. I've never like loose typing... :-/

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061760/how-to-read-aloud-python-list-comprehensions help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've seperated the line apart wrong, start from the outer point with the list comprehension in the form of

```
[          <code_that_gets_value>        for <element>  in  <iterable>]
[np.array(list(map(int,box.split(',')))) for    box      in   line[1:]]
```

### The iterable

```
line[1:]
```

This just uses python slicing to get a list that is everything in line from the first index onwards (omits index 0 element)

### The element

```
box
```

This is the element of the iterable that you're currently iterating on

### Code that gets value

```
np.array(list(map(int,box.split(','))))
```

map is equivalent (similar but thats another story) to

```
 [int(x) for x in box.split(',')]
```

except in python 3, it returns a generator that needs converting into a list in order to be a valid parameter to go into the numpy array

The output of all of this is another list that then gets put into a numpy array. To be precise, its a 2 dimensional numpy array full of integers

Comment: I'm running this in python 3, so does the last line change functionality?

Comment: I do not think *iterator* is a good word choice, because it already means something else in Python. EDIT: In the grammar, it is merely called a ["target list"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension).

Comment: Also note, `map` does *not* return a generator in Python 3, it returns *an iterator*. All generators are iterators, but not all iterators are generators.

Comment: @tuskiomi - the only difference in terms of python 2/3 is `map` already returned a list in python 2 so there was no need for `list()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks! I've been using a lot of `yield` lately and confused myself.. (I never use map).  I've changed it to element because target list still sounds like a crappy name to me